# Proving that every proper elementary extension of the real numbers has an infinitesimal element.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I'm not sure how to show that every proper elementary extension of the real numbers has an infinitesimal element. I've been trying to somehow apply the property

$$\forall x \forall y (((\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\lvert x - y \rvert < \varepsilon)) \leftrightarrow x = y)$$

because it seemed useful, although I have no better reason to believe this. If a nonstandard model has no infinitesimal element, then $(\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\lvert x - y \rvert < \varepsilon)$ is equivalent to $(\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+) (\lvert x - y \rvert < \varepsilon)$ where $\mathbb{R}$ is the natural embedding of the standard model, so perhaps this is somehow useful. Unsure how to proceed.

Comment: You're thinking about this the wrong way.  Take some nonstandard element $x$, and think about where it could possibly be relative to the real line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R$ be a proper elementary extension of $\mathbb{R}$, and $r\in R\setminus \mathbb{R}$.

- Case 1: $r>q$ for all $q\in \mathbb{Q}$. Then $1/r$ is a positive infinitesimal.
- Case 2: $r<q$ for all $q\in \mathbb{Q}$. Then $-1/r$ is a positive infinitesimal.
- Case 3: The sets $A = \{q\in \mathbb{Q}\mid q < r\}$ and $B = \{q\in \mathbb{Q}\mid r < q\}$ are both non-empty. If $A$ has a greatest element $a$, then $(r-a)$ is a positive infinitesimal. If $B$ has a least element $b$, then $(b-r)$ is a positive infinitesimal. If neither, then $(A,B)$ is a Dedekind cut corresponding to some irrational real number $s$. Depending on whether $r<s$ or $s<r$, either $(s-r)$ or $(r-s)$ is a positive infinitesimal.

Comment: Instead of splitting the case 3 into three subcases, you can just say that the set $A$ is bounded and nonempty, so it has a supremum $s\in \mathbf R$. Then it is immediately clear from the definition that $r-s$ is infinitesimal.